SQL query runs when commands are run seperately but not when run as a whole
I have a SQL query to add a computed column to a system versioned table. System versioned tables ofcourse don't allow this, so I turn off system versioning first. Query below:
--Run in tran so system versioning resets on error    
BEGIN TRAN

    ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Table] SET (SYSTEM_VERSIONING = OFF);

    ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Table] ADD [OBJID] AS SUBSTRING([OBJECTID],3,48) PERSISTED;
    
    ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Table_history] ADD [OBJID] NVARCHAR(48) NULL;

    ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Table] SET (SYSTEM_VERSIONING = ON (HISTORY_TABLE = [dbo].[Table_history] , DATA_CONSISTENCY_CHECK = OFF ));

COMMIT TRAN

The issue is when I run this query as a whole it gives the following error:
System-versioned table schema modification failed because adding computed column while system-versioning is ON is not supported.

However when I run it step by step by just selecting each line and running the selection it works just as intended. I've been staring at this for way too long, any help would be greatly appreciated.

When runnas a single batch versions is on, so the parsing fails.

Put a GO after the first alter

I'm a bit ashamed I didn't think of this. Thanks!

I've ended up fixing this by doing the following:
   DECLARE @sql nvarchar(max)
   BEGIN TRAN

    ALTER TABLE [hix].[VRLIJST_LSTOPSLG] SET (SYSTEM_VERSIONING = OFF);


    SET @sql = 'ALTER TABLE [hix].[VRLIJST_LSTOPSLG] ADD [OBJID] AS SUBSTRING([OBJECTID],3,48) PERSISTED;'
    EXEC(@sql)

    
    SET @sql = 'ALTER TABLE [hix].[VRLIJST_LSTOPSLG_history] ADD [OBJID] NVARCHAR(48) NULL;'
    EXEC(@sql)

    ALTER TABLE [hix].[VRLIJST_LSTOPSLG] SET (SYSTEM_VERSIONING = ON (HISTORY_TABLE = [hix].[VRLIJST_LSTOPSLG_history] , DATA_CONSISTENCY_CHECK = OFF ));


COMMIT TRAN

Earlier comments triggered me to do this. Thanks for the help!

As a side note, it's generally advised to not use syntax such as EXEC (@SQL);. Such statements cannot be parametrised, which promote bad habits that result in security flaws like SQL injection. If you need to run a statement that is within a variable or literal string then use sys.sp_executesql. Then you can easily parametrise the statement if you need to.

DDL cannot be parameterized.

@DavidBrowne-Microsoft Except for BACKUP and RESTORE oddly enough, and ALTER PARTITION FUNCTION and some DBCC commands

Yes inconsistent.  But only ALTER PARITITION FUNCTION is DDL.  Commands like BACKUP and DBCC are a different category.
